# How to put background color behind a vtktextactor?

Tags: python, background, vtk

I'm trying to display some contextual information over an image where the user clicked.

I'm using vtkTextActor for this. I'm using the python bindings.

The problem is that because it is over an image it is diffcult to read, I would like to draw some background behind it. (maybe a little square polydata, something simple).But I need to know what the text extent is and I can't figure out how to use text.GetSize()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be using the member function `SetBackgroundColor` and `SetBackgroundOpacity` of `vtkTextProperty` of `vtkTextActor`.

Use of `text.GetSize()` is not necessary for the background, but in case it is useful, you can call `GetBoundingBox(renderer, vector)` of the `vtkTextActor`.

See [vtkTextProperty Class Reference](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTextProperty.html)

Demo:

[image: Demo of vtkTextActor with background and border]

```py
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import vtkmodules.vtkRenderingOpenGL2
import vtkmodules.vtkRenderingFreeType    # necessary for vtkTextActor

from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import (
    vtkRenderWindow,
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor,
    vtkRenderer,
)
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import vtkTextActor

# window initialization
renderer = vtkRenderer()
render_window = vtkRenderWindow()
render_window.SetSize([800, 150])
render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
interactor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)

# construct the text object
text_actor = vtkTextActor()
text_actor.SetInput("Hello vtkTextActor()\n     also you might set SetFrameColor.")                        # you can have multi-line text
prop = text_actor.GetTextProperty()
prop.SetFontSize(28)
prop.SetFontFamilyToCourier()
prop.SetColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
prop.SetBackgroundColor(0.0, 0.2, 0.5)  # set the background color
prop.SetBackgroundOpacity(1.0)          # 1.0 = opaque, 0.0 = transparent
#prop.SetBackgroundRGBA(0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5)  # alternative
prop.FrameOn()                          # bounding box
text_actor.SetPosition(50, 50)
renderer.AddActor2D(text_actor)

# present the window
interactor.Initialize()
renderer.ResetCamera()
render_window.Render()
interactor.Start()
```